# the database system to store any value associated with such external writes temporarily in a special relation in the database

Tags: database-design

The text below is from the book Database System Concepts by Silberschatz.
Why the values associated with external writes need to be stored in a special relation in the database? Can't we behave with these values like other values?

> We must be cautious when dealing with observable external writes, such as writes
> to a user’s screen, or sending email. Once such a write has occurred, it cannot be
> erased, since it may have been seen external to the database system. Most systems
> allow such writes to take place only after the transaction has entered the committed
> state. One way to implement such a scheme is for **the database system to store any value
> associated with such external writes temporarily in a special relation in the database**,
> and to performthe actual writes only after the transaction enters the committed state. If
> the system should fail after the transaction has entered the committed state, but before
> it could complete the external writes, the database system will carry out the external
> writes (using the data in non-volatile storage) when the system is restarted.

Comment: "Can't we behave with these values like other values?" That's exactly what is suggested: you store them in a (special) relation, because they are special, transient entities.

Comment: Many thanks! I think they mean that instead of executing the actual writes they now perform a fake writes and store that values in a special relation to database, then after the committed state they perform actual write, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can't we behave with these values like other values?

That's exactly what is suggested in your quote: you store data to be written externally in a (special) relation, because they are special, transient entities.

Suppose you have a workflow system in which a `task` is assigned to a user by updating its `user_id` attribute ("internal write"). It also needs to send an email notification (an external write) to that user. These two happen asynchronously, but the external one must always happen after the internal one is persisted. You update the `task` record as usual (nothing "fake" about it) and create a new `outbound_email` entity with whatever information is relevant. When the `task` update is committed, you process `outbound_email` and delete the transient record.

This works pretty much like a write-ahead log for external actions: you first create a record for the action, then perform that action at an appropriate moment, then discard the log record as it is no longer needed. If the flow is interrupted, you replay the "log" to recover.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great explanation!    Sorry, if we don't write that values in a special relation to the database that is like  a write-ahead log for external actions, and we write them in the original log that is written after the final statement of the transaction, what would happen? What would be the difference?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here; what do you mean by the "original log" that is "written after the final statement"?

Comment: Each transaction has a log file. The transaction writes its information into that log file after the final statement of the transaction. By original log I mean this log. So I'm asking why that values aren't written in this log file? Why we have to write them in a special relation to the database? Many thanks!

Comment: Firstly, transactions don't have log files. The database engine maintains its log files, where all changes are recorded. A set of changes constitutes a transaction. Secondly, changes are written to the transaction log _before_ the transaction is committed (and even if it's _never_ committed). Finally, since it's the _database_ log, any changes, including the added and deleted rows in the "special relation", _are_ indeed written to that log. _You_ have no control over the log content; for the database to write anything to the log _you_ must write that anything to a table.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much for the great explanations!!!